# How to edit this code in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have a theme called EasyVersion: 1.2 By D5 Creation. For the comment box section I want to change the text so it says something different than Post Comment. I have searched and searched every where, even searched for the code using All Files search.

This I presume is the code:

```
<input id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Post Comment" name="submit">
```

Can someone tell me how I can please locate this. It's not in comments.php or anywhere like this.

I am not so good at these type of things, so if you can explain clearly what I need to do that would be awesome.

Comment: I tried to Google that theme and found nothing. However, it could be located in your functions.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your templates are rendering the default `<?php comment_form(); ?>`, or something along those lines. There are a couple of ways you can handle this.

The first way is to simply find the call to `comment_form()` in the template(s) making this call, and pass in an argument like so:

```
<?php comment_form(array('label_submit' => __('Post an awesome Comment'))); ?>
```

The other way - **and bear in mind that I haven't tested it** - is to alter the default fields globally through an action hook.

In *functions.php*, add the following:

```
add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'modify_comment_fields');
function modify_comment_fields($fields){
    $fields['label_submit'] = __('Post an awesome Comment');
    return $fields;
}
```

That should get you started on the right track.

[More information on comment_form() here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)

Comment: Thank you very much, the code you mentioned for functions.php worked perfectly ;)